# iOSの位置情報を比較したい

Tags: ios, objective-c

CLLocationCoordinate2Dのlatitude同士の値を下記のように比べているのですがうまく比較できません。
比較できる方法はありますでしょうか？

```
double lat1 = (double)self.mapView.centerCoordinate.latitude;
double lon1 = (double)self.mapView.centerCoordinate.longitude;

double lat2 = (double)newLocation.coordinate.latitude;
double lon2 = (double)newLocation.coordinate.longitude;

if (((lat1 - lat2) < 1.0f) && ((lon1 - lon2) < 1.0f)) {
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`MKMetersBetweenMapPoints`を利用します。

```
MKMapPoint p1 = MKMapPointForCoordinate(self.mapView.centerCoordinate);
MKMapPoint p2 = MKMapPointForCoordinate(newLocation.coordinate);

if (MKMetersBetweenMapPoints(p1, p2) < 100.0) { // 距離が100m未満
```

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。
確認してみます。

Answer (score 3):

if分の条件を下記のように修正してみてはいかがでしょうか？

```
if ((fabs(lat1 - lat2) < 1.0f) && (fabs(lon1 - lon2) < 1.0f)) {
```

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。
確認してみます。